# Add local server to MongoDB Atlas cloud instance

Tags: mongodb

At the moment I use a MongoDB Atlas cloud instance to host the database I use for an electronic display.

The display is realized as a Node.js app running on a Raspberry Pi 3B.
The Pi boots into a web browser in kiosk mode.

Sometime the WiFi of the Pi breaks because the router crashes. Then the app does not get data anymore.

That's why I would like to setup a MongoDB server on that Raspberry Pi and add that server to the cloud cluster OR replicate the server on a regular basis.

As I need to manage the data from home and have no remote access to the Pi, I want to keep the cloud instance.

Is that possible? And if yes: how?

Comment: You cannot add on-premises db to atlas, but you could host it yourself e.g. on AWS using atlas-like UI https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager. There are few other problems with your approach - size of the repset is limited, replication over wi-fi is unreliable, re-joining the set may result with data loss, no ssl support on the pi etc. I'd say couchdb would suit more. It was designed for this exact usecase - sync of the embedded db over unreliable network.

Comment: MongoDB Replica set can have up to 50 members, any data transfer via unreliable network will be problematic, proper ‘writeconcern’ settings should prevent data loss on rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible?

No, you cannot add your own instances to [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) (either on-premise or cloud).

> That's why I would like to setup a mongodb- server on that raspberry pi and add that server to the cloud cluster OR replicate the server on a regular basis.

If you are running Android (with API level 24+) on your Pi, you can register for [MongoDB Mobile (beta)](https://www.mongodb.com/products/mobile).

MongoDB Mobile provides a few core benefits:

- Persist data directly on-device
- Use consistent, standard access patterns across device, backend, and database

In the near future, MongoDB Mobile will also support syncing data between local and remote MongoDB instances. See also [MongoDB Mobile manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mobile/mobile-overview/)

Comment: thank you for the definitive "no". I might go and switch to couchdb as suggested by Alex in the comments... or leave it as is and make the wifi more stable...

Comment: You could also post another question related to how to handle loss of connectivity to a database backend.